# frida issue. hooking static method call

Tags: android, security, hook, code-injection, frida

I am trying to learn Frida and have experimented with a little so far. Things have mostly worked as thankfully I could find enough examples and tutorials to help me through. However, at this point in time, I am stuck with a very specific task at hand.

So let's say below is the Frida hook I am referring to:

```
Java.perform(() => {
      const TestClass = Java.use(
        'com.test.TestClass',
      );
      TestClass.testStaticMethod.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.util.Map').implementation = function (
        str,
        map,
      ) {


        console.log('intercept!');
        return this.b(str, map);
      };
      const testStr = Java.use('java.lang.String').$new('test');
      const testMap = Java.use('java.util.HashMap').$new();
 });
 //wait (sleep) 10-15 secs
 Java.perform(() => {
      // test it!   
      TestClass.testStaticMethod(testStr, testMap);
    });
```

it does NOT output 'intercept!'
What could be the reason?

Comment: I have doubts about the overload. You are using a HashMap but you overload a Map. From what I see at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html, HashMap implements Map interface but doesn't extend it, so you might enter another overload instead. You should try ``TestClass.testStaticMethod.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.util.HashMap')`` or ``TestClass.testStaticMethod.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.util.AbstractMap')``.

Comment: Denzel please do never post multi-line code in comments because it is totally unreadable there! Instead please edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score -1):

The call to `TestClass.testStaticMethod(testStr, testMap);` in your script does not execute the hook, but the original un-hooked method. Therefore you will never see the output `intercept!` when your script is loaded.

The output `intercept!` will only be generated if the hooked method is executed by the app.